# Combining boostrap carousel with checkboxes in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Hello guys I'm working on implementing bootstrap carousel in my WordPress project. I'm using checkboxes to list my categories it looks something like this:
[image]

I would like for users to be able to change content of my carousel based on categories they choose.
Basically I need to change my query based on which checkboxes user has choosen. My query needs to change based on what categories user has choosen for example something like this  'category_name' => 'test1, test2'
 
This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-4 main-content">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allRadios" id="allRadios" value="all">
        all
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="frontendRadios" id="frontendRadios" value="frontend" checked>
        front end
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="wordpressRadios" id="wordpressRadios" value="wordpress" checked>
        wordpress
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="designRadios" id="designRadios" value="design" checked>
        design
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seoRadios" id="seoRadios" value="seo" checked>
        seo
      </label>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Here starts carousel loop -->
<?php $carauselLoop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'category_name' => 'testing' ) ); ?>
<?php $i=1; ?>
<div class="col-md-4 our-work-info">
    <div class="clients-num">
        <h5 title="01">01</h5>
    </div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
    <h3>Crossroads</h3>
    <h4 class="sub-heading">front end / wordpress</h4>
</div>

<div class="col-md-7">

    <div id="our-work-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <?php while ( $carauselLoop->have_posts() ) : $carauselLoop->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="item <?php if ($i == 1) echo 'active'; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">


               <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators our-work-indicators">
        <li data-target="#our-work-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#our-work-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#our-work-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#our-work-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#our-work-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this and how should I approach it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to take a different approach in solving this.
My idea was to load all posts from different categories and give them CSS classes which I would then show or not show based on which checkboxes user selected.
This is my HTML:

```
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php while ( $carouselLoop->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php $carouselLoop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php
            $categories = get_the_category();
            $cat = '';
            if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                $cat = esc_html( $categories[0]->name );
            }
        ?>
        <div
            class="cat-all cat-<?= strtolower($cat) ?> item <?php if ($i == 1) echo 'active'; ?>"
            data-title="<?php the_title() ?>"
            data-category="<?= strtolower($cat) ?>"
        >
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

This is my JQ:

```
    var checkedCategories = {
    frontend: false,
    testing: false,
    uncategorized: false,
    wordpress: false,
    design: false,
    seo: false,
};

function checkedKeys() {
    return Object.keys(checkedCategories).filter(function(key) {
        return checkedCategories[key];
    });
}

function toggleAll() {
    Object.keys(checkedCategories).forEach(function(key) {
        checkedCategories[key] = false;
        $('#' + key + 'Chb').attr('checked', false);
    });
    $('.cat-all').addClass('item').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.cat-all').eq(0).addClass('active');

    $('#allChb').attr({
        disabled: true,
        checked: true
    });
}

$('#category-checkboxes').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function(e) {
    var $chb = $(this);
    var category = $chb.data('category');

    $('.cat-all').removeClass('active');

    if (category == 'all') {
        if (this.checked) {
            toggleAll();
            return;
        } else {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }
    }

    $('.cat-all').removeClass('item').addClass('hidden');

    if (this.checked) {
        $('#allChb').attr({
            disabled: false,
            checked: false
        });
    }

    var $catItems = $('.cat-' + category);
    checkedCategories[category] = this.checked;

    var categories = checkedKeys();
    if (categories.length === 0) {
        toggleAll();
        return;
    }

    categories.forEach(function(cat) {
        var checked = checkedCategories[cat];
        var $catItems = $('.cat-' + cat);
        $catItems.addClass('item');
        $catItems.removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $('.cat-all.item').eq(0).addClass('active');
});
```

If anyone runs into similar issue I hope this will help him.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in PHP means doing page reloads for every checkbox click and this is generally not what you want. You're wasting a lot of user's time and putting a needless load on your server. That being said, what you want to do is expose a custom query parameter that you then pass along to the function querying the posts.

So you'd add something like this to `functions.php`:

```
public function add_query_vars($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'carousel_cat';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

Then wherever you run the query you first fetch the query param from the URL:

```
$carousel_categories = get_query_var('carousel_cat', false) ?: '1,2'; // '1,2' are defaults
// Let's assume the URL is /?carousel_cat=12,43 then $carousel_categories = '12,43'
```

And pass that to your query:

```
// The numbers should be category IDs because then you can pass them directly to the query:
$carauselLoop = new WP_Query(['cat' => $carousel_categories]);
// But you might wanna do some kind of sanitation on that so that ti doesn't error out
```

For the checkboxes' values make sure to output the category IDs. Also, don't hardcode them, but loop through categories:

```
<?php
  $available_categories = get_categories();
  foreach($available_categories as $cat):
?>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>"> <?= esc_html($cat->name); ?></label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And you will still need some kind of JS logic that will listen for `onchange` events on the inputs, and set correct URL e.g. `http://yoursite.tld/?carousel_cat=12`.

Comment: Thank you I will try to implement what you wrote and maybe ask you here in comments additional questions if I get stuck somewhere.